# Using z-index with infowindow and CartoDB CSS?

Tags: carto, infowindow

I currently have a map where my map div covers 60% of the page and 40% is a fixed  Infowindow. My problem happens with cartodb css and its z-index of `div.cartodb-infowindow`.
Currently my information will not show in the fix div, however the html elements are there when I click on a point and if I manually go into the debugger and un-check the cartodb-infowindow, the information will show up.

So in my styles sheet I added .cartodb-infowindow and tried setting the z-index to a higher number than my side panel but no luck. I have tried a lower number and even setting the z-index to none. However I cannot override the cartodb css on z-index. (I have also tried using !important as well).

Comment: for what I understand the info is displayed under the info-window because the z-index is lower. Use firebug to know what css class affects the info-window and what z-index value is used. Then define a z-index a little higher to the information class

Comment: if not working use the !important tag beside the z-index css property to overide any other property that can affect the element

Comment: I am using firebug to track down where the index problem exist and as stated above I had already tried using !important. After a hour I ended up downloading cartodb.css from github instead of linking the css and manually changing the z-index to :initial and that worked for me.

Comment: good to hear that. I have encounter that kind of situation before, and came to the same conclusion. It's better to have your own version of the css than linking to it.

Comment: Could you mark the question as answered if this was solved in the comments? :)